# Set HTTP EndPoint to receive POST from an API

Tags: angular, typescript, http, request, http-headers

I have an Angular application and need to receive [Webhooks](https://dev.moip.com.br/v1.5/reference#webhooks-1) from the Moip Payments API and I need to create an ***EndPoint to receive POST*** when an event occurs.

How do I create an EndPoint so that Moip can send these events that occur to my application in a secure way?

In localhost I can not perform the tests, I need a way to define a URL that only with a permission can do the POST.

I want to make sure that only Moip will communicate with my application.

**My big question is how to prepare my application in Angular to receive data through the API I am using.**

Here is an example of what I need to do:

**moip-service.ts:**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';


private api_URL = 'https://sandbox.moip.com.br/assinaturas/v1/';
private notification_URL = 'minha_url_notificacoes';

private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': environment.MoipAPI.apiKey
    })
};

constructor(
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private http: HttpClient) {
    }

getNotifications(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get(this.notification_URL)
            .subscribe((response: any) => {
                resolve();
            }, reject);
    }
);
}
```

Comment: There is no documentation in English, but you can use the tool to translate to Google Chrome from the documentation pages if you need to.

My application already does communication with the API, I created an @Injectable () service and I use HttpClient to do POST, GET, PUT, DELETE. Everything is working properly, the only problem is that I do not know what to do to create an EndPoint so that I receive a JSON API when an event occurs through WebHooks.

Comment: Yes you're right, that's right. I need to listen to what Moip sends me, but for this I need to prepare my application to receive POST from the Moip API.

I do a POST indicating to Moip which URL I want to receive the POST. But I need to create this EndPoint in my application to receive a JSON and I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Thanks, this is a big problem for me because I need as many before homologating this API in my application, but for this I need to receive Webhooks.

You will help me a lot with this and I will be very grateful to you.

Comment: Have you found the answer finally?